# Package a node app for the browser using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

So this may be naive, but can I run node only style apps in the browser? I've see tuts for frontend stuff. I've seen tuts for backend stuff. I want to run https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray in a browser and do something quick and dirty like (this code may not be perfect)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var phantom = require('x-ray-phantom');
  var Xray = require('x-ray');

  var x = Xray()
    .driver(phantom());

  x('http://google.com', 'body')(function(err, str) {
    $( "body" ).replaceWith( "str" );
  });
});
```

To do a whole site pass though without an iframe. The purpose is so I can re-write CSS on internal company assets in sort of a global fashion. I'll be able to just pass a url and the page will be displayed. If I have custom css for it, then that will be active. I still gotta work out auth, but im not worried about it at this exact moment.

I've used x-ray with express in the past and it worked like a charm. In this context though I've taken a liking to Laravel and would like to stand up my apps in that.

The latest Laravel has "mix", a web pack front end. It works great for frontend assets. If I try to webpack x-ray though, I run into a flurry of issues like:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve yadayadayada

So you can set an export like this:

```
module.exports.node = {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
};
```

While that fixes module errors, I feel like I need those things. and in the browser I get:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "child_process"

I have a feeling things like this are not supposed to work, but I'm hoping I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: you can't use Node built-in modules like `fs` or `net`, and therefore modules that use them, in the browser.

You can empty them out as you did with the `node` option, but the modules that depend on them use them for a reason and you would break them, unless you know exactly that the part, that uses the built-in modules, will not end up in your application, or at least you're not using it.

In your case, first it complained about `fs`, which clearly doesn't make sense in the browser, because you don't have access to the file system. And then it complains about `child_process`, so somewhere in the module it spawns processes, but you can't do that in the browser either, and emptying that out will very likely break the module's functionality, so you'd need to look for another module, that can be used in the browser.